# How are local admin accounts handled in a DFARS compliant environment?

Tags: passwords, nist, administration

In most IT departments that I've been apart of we've had local administrator accounts that we can use when the given machine, for some reason, doesn't have network access, or domain access.

One of the DFARS requirements is that all accounts local and network based have Dual Factor Authentication.  I've achieved DFA for all accounts attached to our AD, but I'm unsure how to proceed with the local admin. accounts.

I've seen options like Duo, but I didn't want to get into a process that's too involved if there was an obvious solution that I haven't thought of yet.